# NullPointerException at addHeaderView and setAdapter

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, custom-lists

> **Note : i have refered similar questions** and still cannot find any mistakes

---

NullPointerException at

```
listView.addHeaderView(header);
```

AND

```
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

---

**detailed code :**

```
Veg v = new Veg();
v.setId(1);
v.setName("some");
v.setPrice(15.0);

List<Veg> vegData = new ArrayList<Veg>();

// dummy add for testing 
vegData.add(v);
vegData.add(v);
vegData.add(v);

CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,
        R.layout.custom_list_rows, vegData);
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);


View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
        R.layout.custom_list_header, null);

listView.addHeaderView(header);

listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**getView() part**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Veg> {

    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    List<Veg> data;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Veg> data) {
        super(context, resource);
        this.context = context;
        this.layoutResourceId = resource;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        CustomHolder holder = null;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new CustomHolder();
            holder.at = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.customheaderbutton1);
            holder.bt = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.customheaderbutton2);
            holder.ct = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.customheaderbutton3);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (CustomHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        holder.at.setText(String.valueOf(data.get(position).getId()));
        holder.bt.setText(data.get(position).getName());
        holder.ct.setText(String.valueOf(data.get(position).getPrice()));

        return row;
    }

    static class CustomHolder {
        TextView at;
        TextView bt;
        TextView ct;
    }

}
```

**main activity xml file**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"> 

     <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**custom_list_header.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/customheaderbutton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:text="marketname" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/customheaderbutton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:text="edit" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/customheaderbutton3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:text="+" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**custom_list_rows.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/elementIDtext"
        android:layout_width="11dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/elementName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.30"
        android:text="@string/elementName"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/elementSummary"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/elementValue"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="62dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/_" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post the xml layout and the code where do you set the layout to the activity

Comment: post code from getView()..

Comment: Find out what is null -- check your logcat. Then make sure it's not null. My guess it's `listView`.

Comment: i am recreating the project now . textview is coming as NULL but a EXTRY EXISTS IN R.JAVA

Comment: I see, there is no R.Id.customheaderbutton1 in row, that is in your header, you want R.Id.elementIDtext, R.Id.elementName, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like `listView` is `null`, which means `findViewById()` returned `null`: it couldn't find the control you're looking for. Without seeing your layout there's no way to debug further, but look to be sure `R.id.listView1` refers to a valid element.

Comment: This would be a comment, not an answer. You're asking for additional information.

Comment: @323go Given the information provided it is the best answer anyone can give him. If more information becomes available I will update this answer. There's nothing wrong with that. Reconsider your downvote.

Comment: And if more information does *not* become available, then your comment just adds noise to Stackoverflow. Please reconsider your "answer" and post one once you have information to actually answer it.

Comment: @323go I'm sorry, I strongly disagree. The information I provided is valuable and might help the OP or others. It explains what the error means and gives a starting point for troubleshooting. With this answer, many people would then be able to go back and figure it out for themselves. If my answer said only "post more" I would agree with you, but it doesn't. It contains legitimate and potentially helpful information about the problem that was posted. To me that is a good description of an "answer."

Comment: i am recreating the project now . textview is coming as NULL but a EXTRY EXISTS IN R.JAVA

Comment: listview was null but i recreated the project and the error is my gone . some internal error i suppose

Answer (score 1):

In getView, change

```
    holder.at = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.customheaderbutton1);
    holder.bt = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.customheaderbutton2);
    holder.ct = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.customheaderbutton3);
```

to

```
    holder.at = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.elementIDtext);
    holder.bt = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.elementName);
    holder.ct = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.elementSummary);
```

Comment: you helped me avoid a different mistake . thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

**Replace your Code With Below:**

```
package com.example.listview;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class List extends Activity 
{
    private ListView listview;
    Veg Veg = new Veg(); 
    ArrayList<Veg> data = new ArrayList<Veg>();
    CustomAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

        listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

        for(int i=1;i<101;i++)
        {
            Veg = new Veg();
            Veg.setName("Item "+i);
            Veg.setID("ID "+i);
            Veg.setPrice("Price "+i);

            data.add(Veg);
        }

         View headerView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                    R.layout.custom_list_header, null);


                listview.addHeaderView(headerView);

                adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,R.layout.custom_list_rows,data);
                listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Veg>
    {
        Context con;
        int Res;
        ArrayList<Veg> data;
        public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Veg> data) {
            super(context, resource,data);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            con = context;
            Res = resource;
            this.data = data;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = convertView;
            CustomHolder holder = null;

            if (row == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                row = inflater.inflate(Res, parent, false);

                holder = new CustomHolder();
                holder.at = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.elementIDtext);
                holder.bt = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.elementName);
                holder.ct = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.elementSummary);
                row.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (CustomHolder) row.getTag();
            }

            holder.at.setText(String.valueOf(data.get(position).getID()));
            holder.bt.setText(data.get(position).getName());
            holder.ct.setText(String.valueOf(data.get(position).getPrice()));

            return row;
        }

        class CustomHolder {
            TextView at;
            TextView bt;
            TextView ct;
        }

    }
}
```

**Also You have to Change your XML Something Like below instead giving Static Width like 11 dp.**

**custom_list_rows.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/elementIDtext"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="ID"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/elementName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="elementName"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/elementSummary"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="elementValue"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="btn" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try this code. I have made small modification in your code. I have tested this & working like Charm.

Comment: got stuck with some compilations .. ill check the var names .. by the way the error is solved points from others posts . thaks for you help